# A strange Maven error message while build is successful

Tags: java, scala, maven

I have got a maven project setup. It uses scala as the language.

When I build this project, it shows all the modules are built successfully.

However, it does contain some [Error] messages which only contains my source path.
I don't quite understand what are those.

Can anyone help? Please see the [Error] tag below.

Many thanks.

```
[INFO] --- maven-scala-plugin:2.9.1:compile (default) @ model ---
[INFO] suggestion: remove the scalaVersion from pom.xml
[ERROR] F:\devel\raven\shared\model\src\main\scala
[INFO] Compiling 1 source files to F:\devel\raven\shared\model\target\classes
[INFO]
```

More Information. Here is my POM's build section:

```
<build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
        <testOutputDirectory>test-output</testOutputDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <executable>${env.JAVA_HOME}/bin/javac</executable>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                </configuration>
                <version>2.3</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-deprecation</arg>
                    </args>
                </configuration>

                <version>2.9.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>target/resources</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
```

More infomation generated using mvn -X clean install.

Here is the relevant debug message:

```
[DEBUG]   (f) scalaClassName = scala.tools.nsc.Main
[DEBUG]   (f) sourceDir = F:\devel\raven\shared\model\src\main\scala\..\scala
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[ERROR] F:\devel\raven\shared\model\src\main\scala
[INFO] Compiling 1 source files to F:\devel\raven\shared\model\target\classes
[DEBUG] cmd:  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\bin\java -classpath C:\Users\kevin\.m2\repository\org\scala-lang\scala-library\2.9.1\scala-library
-2.9.1.jar;C:\Users\kevin\.m2\repository\org\scala-lang\scala-compiler\2.9.1\scala-compiler-2.9.1.jar -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\Users\kevin\.m2\repository\
org\scala-lang\scala-library\2.9.1\scala-library-2.9.1.jar scala.tools.nsc.Main -deprecation -classpath F:\devel\raven\shared\model\target\classes;C:\
Users\kevin\.m2\repository\log4j\log4j\1.2.16\log4j-1.2.16.jar;C:\Users\kevin\.m2\repository\org\scala-lang\scala-compiler\2.9.1\scala-compiler-2.9.1.
jar;C:\Users\kevin\.m2\repository\org\scala-lang\scala-library\2.9.1\scala-library-2.9.1.jar -d F:\devel\raven\shared\model\target\classes F:\devel\ra
ven\shared\model\src\main\scala\com\mxyy\shared\model\Customer.scala
```

More Information:

One thing I fotgot to mention is that this used to be a Java project and I changed it to a scala project by renaming src/main/java to src/main/scala and added this bits:

```
<sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
<testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
<testOutputDirectory>test-output</testOutputDirectory>
```

I then added all the scala related dependencies.

The error message shown above does not really cause any problems. but it indicates there might be some configurations wrong in my POM.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably remove the [scalaVersion](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/maven-scala-plugin/usage.html) tag as the warning says. "Since version 2.7 of the plugin, the scala version to use is detected from dependency to scala-library. So it suggested to not use scalaVersion configuration"

Next try mvn -X clean install the x will take maven into debug mode and add more info to logs, please post those logs

Answer (score 0):

Can you try setting maven compiler version to `2.3.2` (the latest version) as of date?  Wondering if you are seeing [this issue](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOMPILER-109), which got fixed in `2.3.2`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This does not seem to solve the problem unfortunately.